# Recyclerview grid layout: Drag outside incompatible with scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I am building an android app with two recyclerviews, one with horizontal LinearLayoutManager and the other one with GridLayoutManager.

I want to allow the items recyclerviews to be dragged and dropped over a trash icon outside of the recyclerviews, obviously to delete the dragged item.

What I have done is:

- Apply **android:clipChildren** in the parent of the two recyclerviews
- Apply **android:clipToPadding** in the recyclerviews

This works perfectly in recyclerview with LinearLayoutManager. I can drag an item and drop it over an icon that is outside of the recylcerview.

I also works in the recyclerview with GridLayoutManager, but with a side effect. When I scroll in the grid recyclerview the scrolled items come out of the recyclerview.

At the ende of this GIF you can see the scrolling issue

[image: Recycler view with android:clipToPadding gets items out on scrolling]

So, Is there any way to allow dragging a recyclerview item outside of the recyclerview boundaries but preventing items comeout when scrolling?

Lots of thanks for your help and suggestions in advance

I tried putting the recyclerview with LinearLayoutManager on top of the recyclerview with GridLayoutManager, to hide the items which came out of the boundaries, but this make a strange behaivour when I drag an item, because the items are there yet, even they are hidden. I could make a GIF if needed

My last option is putting the trash icon inside of the recyclerview, as a header that appears when dragging an item, but I would prefer not do it that way

Answer (score 0):

Finally what I have learnt is that you have two main options when face a drag and drop problem:

1. Easy way: Using the Android helper ItemTouchHelper
2. Hard way: Not using the helper and type all the code, using startDragAndDrop()

A scenario like this only can be solved by the hard way.